# How to execute an unknown method for a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm on a small pet project which is to write an app to probe specific services in our environment and check for health.

For now I am focusing only on WCF. We have several different services I'd like to probe and I am trying to build my code as agnostic as possible so I can come later and just plug in the individual services.

Below is the Interface I am writing, that will later be implemented by the individual services. My struggle right now is that I can't find a way to pass in the specific method name I want to execute. Is there even a way to do this?

```
public class IWCFComponent : IDisposable
{
    private System.ServiceModel.IServiceChannel wcfService;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void LoadComponent(IServiceChannel wcfService)
    {
        _wcfService = wcfService;
    }

    public ProbeResults Test(string methodName, string expectedResult)
    {
        /*Need to know how to execute methodName for wcfService */
    }
}
```

Comment: SOAP endpoints? It sounds like reflection is part of the answer:, something like: `foreach(var service in List<IServiceContracts) { http.Test(service.Name) ; } ` (very pseudo)

Comment: Yes, reflection is the way to do it. Do note; it you are using http-binding only, you can also use a http client.

Comment: It seems that the interface is on the server side. Does that passed method name execute on the server side. I could not get your point. Commonly, the client should have known the method that the service contract exposes.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Not perfect as I am struggling with the different soap envelopes but it is a good start if someone has the same situation:

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Not perfect as I am struggling with the different soap envelopes but it is a good start if someone has the same situation:

```
foreach (WCFService service in _servicesToProbe)
        {
            ProbeResults probeResult = new ProbeResults();
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory = service.ServiceBinding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(new BindingParameterCollection());
            factory.Open();
            EndpointAddress address = service.EndpointURL;
            IRequestChannel irc = factory.CreateChannel(address);
            try
            {
                using (irc as IDisposable)
                {
                    irc.Open();
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(String.Format(@"<{0} xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><composite xmlns:a='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><a:value>10</a:value></composite></{0}>", service.ActionName));
                    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
                    Message m = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, String.Format("http://tempuri.org/{0}/{1}", service.InterfaceName, service.ActionName), reader);
                    Message ret = irc.Request(m);
                    reader.Close();
                    factory.Close();
                    probeResult = ProcessResponse(ret, service);
                    _probeResults.Add(probeResult);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                factory.Close();
                probeResult = new ProbeResults(service.ServiceName, false, ex.Message);
                _probeResults.Add(probeResult);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            probeResult.TimeElapsed = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
```